Can we put external credentials in a managed package?
I need to put a named credential and external credential in my managed package that I create. Furthermore, if not possible like this is it possible to create via the postInstall script??

Also, Refer to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_managed_packages.htm&release=248&type=5
